# Why derived class pointer cannot be assigned a base classes' pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I m learning in c++ from the textbook but still confusing

C++ Programme:

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A\n";
    }
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B()
    {
        std::cout << "B is derived class\n";
    }
};


int main()
{

    A * a=new A();  //valid 
    B * b=new B();  //valid

    A * aa=new B(); //valid    why?
    B * bb=new A(); //invalid  why?                                  run time error: invalid conversion from ‘A*’ to ‘B*’ [-fpermissive]

    return 0;
}
```

this line

```
A * a=new A();  //valid
```

use because **I want to access class a**

**and**

this line

```
B * b=new B();  //valid
```

use because **I want to access class b**

and

I m writing this line learning purpose I don't know but this is valid why??

```
A * aa=new B();  //valid
```

and

I m writing this line learning purpose I don't know but this is not valid why??

```
B * bb=new A(); //not valid
```

please explain the last two lines still confusion?

programme link: https://onlinegdb.com/Sy8xkt38L

Comment: `B * bb=new A(); //invalid  why?` - because an A isn't a B.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9716597).  The "is-a" relationship is a very fundamental OOP concept.

Comment: Replace `A` with `Shape` and `B` with `Rectangle`.   Rectangle is a Shape, but a Shape is not necessarily a Rectangle.

Comment: To add up on the comment from @L.F. : as a beginner, you should **not** use `new` to allocate object. With modern C++, this should be used only in very specific situations. Just instanciate with `A a;`

Comment: @L.F. According to the first sentence they already have a book. (Whether good or not, I don't know. Probably not if it starts with `new`.)

Answer (score 3):

This

```
class B: public A
```

effectively says all B's are A's, Its like

```
class Lion : public Animal
```

says *all lions are animals*.

So this is OK

```
Animal* a = new Lion();
```

because all lions are animals. It's safe to assume that a lion is an animal. But this is not OK

```
Lion* l = new Animal();
```

because *not all animals are lions*. You can't take any old animal and pretend it's a lion.